# Rails _ Friends of Users Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, model-associations, self-reference

I'm creating a RoR mock facebook where Users can add each other as friends. I'm having trouble accessing the friend relationship from one side of the friendship. For example, I have user 'Ben' who adds user 'Jordan'. This action goes through the friendships controller below

```
    def create
        @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(friend_id: params[:friend_id], confirmed: false)
        if @friendship.save
            flash[:notice] = "Friend Request Sent."
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Unable to send friend request."
            redirect_to root_url
        end
    end
```

The User Model below has methods to help me access information about each user.
In rails console after I had accepted the friend request, I search for each users friends. After designating `ben` to be the ben user object, and `jordan` to be the jordan user object in the rails console I look up `ben.friends_list` and `ben.friends` and jordan shows up for both. But when I look up `jordan.friends_list` and `jordan.friends` I get a blank array and blank Active Record Association.

When I look up the friendship that exists between them that was created when Ben added Jordan it says it exists between them both. (Ben's ID = 4 and Jordans ID = 3) `#<Friendship id: 1, user_id: 4, friend_id: 3, confirmed: true, created_at: "2020-07-25 19:12:06", updated_at: "2020-07-25 19:24:26">`

I think the problem may be in my associations, or in the model methods for my User. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  
  has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_friendships, source: :user
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  def friends_list
    friends_array = friendships.map{|friendship| friendship.friend if friendship.confirmed}
    friends_array + inverse_friendships.map{|friendship| friendship.user if friendship.confirmed}
    friends_array.compact
  end

  #users who haven't accepted friend request
  def pending_friends
    friendships.map{|friendship| friendship.friend if !friendship.confirmed}.compact
  end

  #users who have requested to be friends
  def friend_requests
    inverse_friendships.map{|friendship| friendship.user if !friendship.confirmed}.compact
  end

  def confirm_friend(user)
    friendship = inverse_friendships.find{|friendship| friendship.user == user}
    friendship.confirmed = true
    friendship.save
  end

  def friend?(user)
    friends_list.include?(user)
  end
end
```

Comment: While I can't offer an immediate suggestion, it seems that based on your description that `inverse_friends` and/or `inverse_friendships` seems to have something wrong (aligning with your thinking). What does `jordan.inverse_friends.to_sql` yield? Is it what you expect?

Comment: ``jordan.friends`` I would expect to be empty, since the friendship relationship is Ben->Jordan.  In that sense, ``.friends`` would only show the friendships the user personally initiated. The problem is likely something with your ``inverse_friendships`` association. I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: Ah, never mind about the associations. When you use ``+`` to concatenate an array, it does not mutate the original, so in ``friends_list`` you concatenate your inverse friends to ``friends_array``, then don't use the result. You can use ``friends_list.concat`` to do a destructive append. Having said that, it would be much more efficient to let the database do the work for you and use a query to generate the list of confirmed friends.

Comment: what is the schema of the friendships table? and what are the associations of the Friendship model?

Answer (score 1):

Hello hope that my answers help you
I personally recommend you to use query-based since it's way much faster and efficient than using Ruby own methods: So for example in order to get **Friendship request** you can use a scope(model method)
`has_many :friendships_requests, lambda { |user| unscope(where: :user_id) .where("status = 'Pending'") .where('friendships.user_id = :user_id OR friendships.other_user_id = :user_id ', user_id: user.id) }, class_name: 'Friendship'`

This scope will give you whether the user_id(sender) or other_user_id(receiver) **status is pending.** So in order to get **friends** you will apply the same methodology but with the difference that the **status is now active** it will go something like this:

`has_many :friends, lambda { |user|unscope(where: :user_id).where("status = 'Active'") .where('friendships.user_id = :user_id OR friendships.other_user_id = :user_id ',user_id: user.id)},class_name: 'Friendship'` both queries are the same but the main difference is the **status**